# Не подключается SSL-сертификат к образу докера

Tags: nginx, docker, ssl, docker-compose

Запустил образ, открыл порты, но при заходе на адрес - все равно пишет **не защищено**, значит сертификат не встал. Что я сделал не так?

Структура части контейнера такая:

- docker-compose.yml
- nginx

  - Dockerfile
  - nginx.conf
- file_setting

  - privkey.pem
  - fullchain.pem

privkey.pem и fullchain.pem - скопировал из папки (там сгенерированные SSL от  Let's Encrypt):

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.ru/

Содержимое **Dockerfile** в папке **nginx**:

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Содержимое **nginx.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 95;
    server_name my_domain.ru www.my_domain.ru;

    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    return 301 https://$host:96$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 96 ssl;
    server_name my_domain.ru www.my_domain.ru;

    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;
    location / {
                  include uwsgi_params;
                  uwsgi_pass app:8095;
                 }
}
```

Содержимое сервиса **nginx** в **docker-compose.yml**:

```
  nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./file_setting/fullchain.pem:/etc/nginx/fullchain.pem
      - ./file_setting/privkey.pem:/etc/nginx/privkey.pem
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: t_nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 95:80
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Answer (score 1):

выглядит странным мапинг порта `- 95:80`. Вы на хосте открываете порт `95` и мапите его в `80` внутри контейнера.
Сделайте так:

```
    ports:
      - 96:96
```

и по адресу `https://my_domain.ru:96` должен быть ваш сертификат

Comment: какая разница на какой порт мапить?

Comment: в контейнере в конфиге nginx открывается два порта `listen 95;` и `listen 96 ssl;`. если вам нужен ssl то мапить нужно 96. Какой порт на хосте не особо важно, выбирайте в зависимости от своих нужд. `- 96:96` написал в качестве примера

Comment: на 80 лежит app. Как тогда с 96 nginx на 80 app прокинуть внутри контейнера?

Comment: у вас в конфиге nginx(nginx.conf), который внутри контейнера открывается всего два порта: `listen 95;` `listen 96 ssl;`. `95` делает редирект на `96`. У `96` на корне отдает `uwsgi_pass app:8095`. в конфиге нет открытия `80` порта